# How to stop the drool execution internally running in a thread

Tags: drools

I am running a rule execution inside the thread. Now I want to stop the execution of the drools internally if the execution is not completed after a particular time.

My question is how can I stop the drool execution when the timeout happens ?

Comment: Probably you can get some details from [here][1]


  [1]: http://drools-moved.46999.n3.nabble.com/How-to-terminate-a-StatefulKnowledgeSession-td3355958.html

Comment: @Prog_G Thanks for your answer. But actually here what I want to do is,  the thread need to communicate with rule to stop if the process is not finished with in a particular time.

Answer (score -1):

Solution for this issue is - create a static variable with default value is true. Put a condition inside the thread using this boolean, so that we need to execute this only when the boolean value is true.   Make that boolean variable to false once the timeout hits.